# Hooking the BootClassLoader

Tags: c++, java, winapi, function-hooking

According to Wikipedia, there are 3 class loaders.

The Boot Class-Loader which loads everything in RT.jar and /../jre/lib

Then the extensions class loader and the system class loader.

I'm only interested in the Boot class loader because I want to hook it and redefine a class in RT.jar without all the legality issues that come with `-Xbootclasspath:/p`.

Docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html

> Note: Applications that use this option to override a class in rt.jar
>   should not be deployed. Doing so would contravene the Java 2 Runtime
>   Environment binary code license.

And the license here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre-6u21-license-159054.txt

states:

> C.  Java  Technology  Restrictions.  You may not  create,  modify,  or
>   change the behavior of, or authorize your licensees to create, modify,
>   or change the behavior of, classes,  interfaces, or  subpackages  that
>   are in any  way  identified  as  "java",  "javax",  "sun"  or  similar
>   convention   as   specified   by  Oracle  in  any  naming   convention
>   designation.

So I'm thinking that if I can hook the boot class loader from native code via C++, I can replace a class in by hooking the `JVM_DefineClass` function from `JVM.dll` without any legal trouble.

The function has the signature:

`JNIEXPORT jclass JNICALL JVM_DefineClass(JNIEnv *env, const char *name, jobject _loader, const jbyte *buf, jsize len, jobject pd)`

- 1: Does this function actually get call when a JVM is starting up?
- 2: Would I still be breaking the license if I hook it?
- 3: Am I hooking the right function or should I be doing something else(better method maybe?)?

Comment: Not a lawyer, but using the boot class loader to replace a class would probably still qualify as changing the behaviour of that class. Besides, very probably you don't have the resources to defend yourself against oracle should they sue you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for legal advice.

Comment: Well.. I did it anyway. It turns out the JVM calls the above function (`JVM_DefineClass` from `JNI.dll`) to define a class. It also calls `Java_lang_lang_DefineClassX` from `Java.dll` where X is a number from 0 to 2 inclusive. Replacing the bytes with your own allows you to redefine any class. Of course, `Xbootclasspath` is easier though.